# Do you change variables AFTER you run a function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I wrote this function from a book I am reading, and this is how it starts:

```
def cheese_and_crackers(cheese_count, boxes_of_crackers):
    print "You have %d cheeses!" % cheese_count
    print "You have %d boxes of crackers!" % boxes_of_crackers
    print "Man that's enough for a party!"
    print "Get a blanket.\n"
```

ok, makes sense. and then, this is when this function is run where I got a little confused and wanted to confirm something:

```
print "OR, we can use variables from our script:"
amount_of_cheese = 10
amount_of_crackers = 50  

cheese_and_crackers(amount_of_cheese, amount_of_crackers)
```

the thing that confused me here is that the amount_of_cheese and amount_of_crackers is changing the variables (verbage? not sure if i am saying the right lingo) from cheese_count and boxes_of_crackers repectively from the first inital variable labels in the function.

so my question is, when you are using a different variable from the one that is used in the initial function you wrote, why would you change the name of the AFTER you wrote out the new variable names? how would the program know what the new variables are if it is shown after it?

i thought python reads programs top to bottom, or does it do it bottom to top?

does that make sense? i'm not sure how to explain it. thank you for any help. :)
(python 2.7)

Comment: Is there anything in existence that reads bottom to top?

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are just a bit confused on the naming rules for parameter passing.

Consider:

```
def foo(a, b):
    print a
    print b
```

and you can call `foo` as follows:

```
x = 1
y = 2
foo(x, y)
```

and you'll see:

```
1
2
```

The variable names of the arguments (`a, b`) in the function signature (1st line of function definition) do not have to agree with the actual variable names used when you invoke the function.

Think of it as this, when you call:

```
foo(x, y)
```

It's saying: "invoke the function `foo`; pass `x` in as `a`, pass `y` in as `b`". Furthermore, the arguments here are passed in as copies, so if you were to modify them inside the function, it won't change the values outside of the function, from where it was invoked. Consider the following:

```
def bar(a, b):
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 2
    print a

x = 0
y = 0
bar(x, y)
print x
print y
```

and you'll see:

```
1
2
0
0
```

Answer (score 2):

The script runs from top to bottom. The function executes when you call it, not when you define it.

I'd suggest trying to understand concepts like variables and function argument passing first.

Answer (score 0):

```
def change(variable):
    print variable

var1 = 1
change(var1)
```

In the above example, `var1` is a variable in the main thread of execution.

When you call a function like change(), the *scope* changes. Variables you declared outside that function cease to exist so long as you're still in the function's scope. However, if you pass it an argument, such as var1, then you can use that value inside your function, by the name you give it in the function declaration: in this case, `variable`. But it is *entirely separate* from `var`! The *value* is the same, but it is a *different variable*!

Answer (score 0):

Your question relates to **function parameter transfer**.

There are two types of parameter transfer into a function:

- By value           ------- value changed in function domain but not global domain
- By reference       ------- value changed in global domain

In python, non-atomic types are transferred by reference; atomic types (like string, integer) is transferred by value.

For example,

Case 1:

```
x = 20
def foo(x): 
    x+=10
foo()
print x // 20, rather than 30
```

Case 2:

```
d = {}
def foo(x): x['key']=20
foo(d)
print d // {'key': 20}
```

Comment: "In python, non-atomic types are transferred by reference; atomic types (like string, integer) is transferred by value." Actually, all parameters are passed by reference.